# Error with single quoted string and mysqli_real_scape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to save a string on my database: `italo's house`

but it's not working. my code:

```
include 'conexao.php';

$organizacao = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['organizacao']); //italo's house

$result = mysqli_query($con, "update organizacao set organizacao = '".$organizacao."'");

if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($con)."update organizacao set organizacao = '".$organizacao."'";
}else{
    header('location:feira.php');
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

I receive a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a prepared statement will resolve the issue with quotes and at the same time help protect you from SQL injection. Try this:

```
$organizacao = $_POST['organizacao'];
$stmt = $con->prepare("update organizacao set organizacao = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $organizacao);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    throw new Exception($stmt->error ." update organizacao set organizacao = '".$organizacao."'");
}else{
    header('location:feira.php');
}
```